# Where i can find valid values for the version attribute of the web-app element in web.xml?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

Typical web.xml looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<web-app version="2.4">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

How can I find out which values are valid for the `version` attribute of `<web-app>`?

```
<web-app version="?">
```

Is it 2.5 or may be 3.0?

Does someone know a URL with the schema or DTD for `web.xml` validation? URL's for DTD of different web-app versions are different is there some source where I can see full list?

```
//doctype for servlet 2.3
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

//doctype for servlet 2.2
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">
```

Comment: You can find all JSR history on http://jcp.org/en/jsr/all and simply do a in-page search then you get all servlet related JSR version. Not sure if there is any Servlet specific version history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this url:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html

Here you can find

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd

Answer (score 2):

The lastreleased is `3.0` (released December 2009) and Wikipedia [shows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet#History) a comprehensive list of versions - `3.0, 2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0, 1.0`. Version `3.1` is in development.

The simplest way I know of to get to the specification(s) is taking the schemaLocation URL `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd` and removing the file part from the end, so navigate to `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/`. This redirects to `http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html` which is a comprehensive source for all specifications. It also has links to the previous J2EE specifications at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

[here I provide link code of schema or DTDs for different Java EE](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/)

In this link you find that

1. Servlet 3.1 deployment descriptor Java EE 7 XML schema
2. Servlet 3.0 deployment descriptor Java EE 6 XML schema
3. Servlet 2.5 deployment descriptor Java EE 5 XML schema
4. Servlet 2.4 deployment descriptor J2EE 1.4 XML schema
5. Servlet 2.3 deployment descriptor J2EE 1.3 DTDs schema